# Is it possible to convert PPT to images in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, com, powerpoint

I tried PIAs until I learned that they're intermediate between .net and COM objects, so it won't be possible unless you have office installed( which, of course is impossible on WP). Is there any other way to do this? If not at the moment, what are the future prospects?

upd. Unfortunately I have to do it without services =(( Nevertheless, thank you for your answers

upd2. Btw, I also wanted to know why is there "no reasonable way" ? I mean there are PDF converter libraries (e.g. C1 ) but there are no Office converter libraries. What are the obstacles so to say?

Comment: When using hard-coded PPT, than variant with SketchFlow is passing. When application require to open arbitrary Ppt file and convert it, then I think you will not find appropriate libraries for WinPhone and I have doubt, that they appear soon or at least appear

Answer (score 1):

Think there is no reasonable way to convert Ppt/Pptx on Windows Phone.

Best way to do it is in your system architecture. Mobile devices are good for client applications. Therefore, you need client and server. Server will be responsible for converting ppt/pptx to images and client will let you to download or see this images, like e.g. Evernote, Dropbox and other do. Even better, when except mobile client and server application, there is also web or desktop clients, which let user to upload ppt/pptx from desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Use SketchFlow ( http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_Overview.aspx) and import your PPT, and it can create XAML out of PPT. You can use the XAML in your app.